# Color Change with button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the colour of a sidebar in my program.  I'm trying to do this just with JavaScript, no JQuery please.

This is the html for my sidebar:

```
    <div class = "sidebar">
        <div class = "receipt">
            <table id = "sideTable">
                <tr class = "sideTR">
                    <th id = "sideTH" class = "h22">RECEIPT</th>
                </tr>   
                <tr class = "sideTR">
                    <td class = "sideTD">
                    <div class = "submit">
                        <input type = "button" onclick = "changeColour()" value = "Change Colour">
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Everything else in my program runs fine but when I put in the function for the colour change none of my functions work anymore.  I feel like the answer is going to be so obvious, but I'm still learning.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Usually if none of my javascript works after adding some new javascript, it usually is because there is an error happening the stops the execution.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var sideReceipt = document.getElementById("receipt");
```

...is looking for an element with an id that doesn't exist. Your element has a *class* of `"receipt"`.

So then the following line:

```
sideReceipt.style.borderColor = "#ee4c11";
```

...will give an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`.

[**The fix**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mn38buf/) is to change that div to have `id="receipt"`.

(I can't explain why *none* of your functions work after you add that function, because it doesn't actually contain any syntax errors even as is, so it'll only give an error when you actually click the button that calls it.)

Answer (score 0):

Please add id in main div like below

```
<div class = "sidebar">  to <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a div with class = "receipt" and getting in JavaScript by getElementById
and its looking for Id not for class. Please change class  to id and it will work fine.